# MVC view not showing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

I'm building a site in MVC 4. After the first view (i.e., home page) shows, I redirect (after some other things) to another view:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "ClaimsSearch", new { carrier = carrier });
```

A breakpoint in that view actually gets hit, and the parameter even has the value:

```
public class ClaimsSearchController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string carrier)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I created a new view (for ClaimsSearchController) by right-clicking on Index, then "Add View." However, after "return View()" executes, the browser still just has the original view sitting there. The new view never appears. By the way, I can type in the second controller name (localhost:1234/ClaimsSearch) and this view DOES show up.

Why does this action not actually show the view?

Comment: your code looks text-book perfect. must be frustrating, but more info needed.

Comment: Any tips on how to troubleshoot it? The breakpoint stops on "return View()" but the old view remains in the browser.

Comment: I've done all MVC for last 2 years and ive never seen anything like it. 1 Q, does this get reproduced for all browsers? and what if you did a redirect from another action?

Comment: Show all the code in your controller. I could only see one action method

Comment: Turns out I was calling the action via an ajax call, which is why the breakpoint was getting hit, but I should've simply been setting the browser location to the controller/action.

Answer (score 0):

Returning View without overloads will default it to look for a file based on the action it is within - For this instance it will be looking for Index.cshtml
It is going to be looking within your View folder, if this controller is within a subfolder of this it'll be looking there for Index.cshtml
By assumption... View/ClaimsSearch/Index
OR it'll be looking within 'View/Shared/'

My suggestion: 
Create a html view file called what it is looking for (Index) or overload the return function to specify another file to look for.
But regardless, I think you're going to have to make an cshtml file within View/ClaimsSearch